# Singular continuous

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, absolute-continuity, singular-measures

I am trying to construct a probability measure which is absolute continuous, singular constinuous and discrete. How can I do? I have not been able to find any example os such a measure. Might you help me? :|

Comment: Are you sure you don't know any absolutely continuous or discrete probability measure at all?  Not knowing any singularly continuous measure is understandable, but ....

Comment: Anyhow, here is an example of a singularly continuous probability measure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_distribution.

Comment: I know absolute continuous and discrete measures. But I would like to find, if it exists a measure such that each component of the lebesgue decomposition is strictly  positive almost everywhere.

Comment: You can take a linear combination of an absolutely continuous measure, a singularly continuous one, and a discrete one.

Comment: Thank you, I feel very stuid now xD